# Linker error using <experimental/filesystem> and calling a function

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17

I am trying to compile a program using the experimental c++ filesystem and am experiencing odd behavior when trying to link my program. I am able to make a fs::path, but calling any function results in a linker error.

I am compiling on Windows 10 using g++.exe (i686-posix-dwarf, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 6.1.0.

The following code compiles:

```
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem::v1;

bool utl::doesExist(const std::string& fileLocation)
{
    fs::path path(fileLocation);
    std::cout << path << std::endl;
    return true;
}
```

However, when trying to use any function I get the same error

```
bool utl::doesExist(const std::string& fileLocation)
{
    fs::path path(fileLocation);
    return fs::exists(fileLocation);
}
```

Makefile:

```
CC          = g++ 
CFLAGS      = -std=c++11 -MP -MD -fPIC

OUTPUT: 
g++ build/Engine.o ... -o bin/libquestia-eng.1.0.0.dll -L lib/SFML-2.4.2-win/lib -lsfml-audio -lsfml-network -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system -lstdc++fs -shared
```

Errors:

```
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/6.1.0/libstdc++fs.a(ops.o):(.text$_Z10_wrealpathPKwPw+0x68): undefined reference to `CreateTransaction@28'

C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/6.1.0/libstdc++fs.a(ops.o):(.text$_Z10_wrealpathPKwPw+0x121): undefined reference to `CommitTransaction@4'
```

I think the problem may lie in the target being a dll, but no amount of searching the internet provided me with a solution. Any ideas about what this linker error means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there's a windows library that you need to link with that is not being included automatically.  The symbols that the linker isn't finding, [`CreateTransaction`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366011(v=vs.85).aspx) and `CommitTransaction`, are in `KtmW32.dll`, so you'll need to include a reference to `KtmW32.lib`.

Comment: I added -lktmw32 after -lstdc++fs and it compiled. Thank you!